# Sphinx: How to extend searching for images to different directories

Tags: image, python-sphinx, directive

By using `image` directive, the images are searched either in the current directory or captured directly with an absolute path.

Is there any way to extend the search path with other directories?

### **Example**

**Environment setup**
Location of the `.rst` file: `project_path/sphinx/source/core/myrst.rst`
Location of the `.png` file: `project_path/doxygen/html/myimage.png`

**Current scenario**
Referencing the `.png` file: 
`.. image::../../../doxygen/html/myimage.png`

**Desired scenario**
Referencing the `.png` file: 
`.. image_or_any_other_directive::myimage.png`

Is there any sphinx extension that provides this functionality?